# Variable Multiple Remainder Difference

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What multiple, m, of a, divided by b, returns a remainder that is c below m?

What formula do you use for this math question?

for example if a is 73 and b, the divisor is 97. Then what multiple, m, is to be multiplied such that the remainder is 35 below m

In this case the answer by searching is 79. That is, (79 x 73) mod 97 = 44 [44 is 35 below 79].

If I don't want to search then how to devise formula to give correct answer?

For example, if a is 475813677834783 and b, the divisor, is 37683749758978594988734958734997589341. Then what multiple, m, is to be multiplied such that the remainder is 6783687436873 below m?

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  Are you assuming that $0≤m-c<b$?   In any case, it looks like you are after the linear congruence $ma\equiv m-c \pmod b$, which has the solution $m\equiv (-c)\times (a-1)^{-1}\pmod b$ at least if $a-1$ is prime to $b$.

Comment: Here is [WA's](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+m*475813677834783%3D%28m-6783687436873%29+mod+37683749758978594988734958734997589341) solution to your specific example.

Comment: As explained in the first comment, this is a linear congruence, and we have many posts which explain how to solve them,, e.g. see the linked dupe and its links.